# What is the difference between rpmsign --addsign and rpm --addsign

Tags: rpm

What is the difference between using `rpmsign --addsign` and `rpm --addsign`, when trying to sign a rpm package? Which one should be used?

I tested the two commands on the same rpm and it seems the behavior is the same:

```
[~]# rpmsign --addsign test.rpm
Enter pass phrase:
Pass phrase is good.
test.rpm:
[~]# rpm -q --qf '%{SIGPGP:pgpsig} %{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n' -p test.rpm
RSA/SHA1, Wed 09 Dec 2020 10:33:31 PM CET, Key ID c5f1c21b5cea63a6 (none)

[~]# rpmsign --delsign test.rpm

[~]# rpm --addsign test.rpm
Enter pass phrase:
Pass phrase is good.
test.rpm:
[~]# rpm -q --qf '%{SIGPGP:pgpsig} %{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n' -p test.rpm
RSA/SHA1, Wed 09 Dec 2020 10:35:01 PM CET, Key ID c5f1c21b5cea63a6 (none)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rpm --addsign
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No such file or directory
```

`rpm --addsign` uses `rpmsign`, i.e. they are the same command.

Aliases are defined in `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt-$VERSION`.

Comment: thanks. Do you have any idea where it's made explicit in the documentation (or the code)?

Comment: check `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt-$VERSION` - it contains all the aliases.

Comment: thank you. That helped me a lot.